# MS ACCESS - SELECT WHERE - Values with forward slash

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have next table:

TABLE: Products

```
Id Type
1  Lact/Liq
2  Lact/Ove
3  Carn/Sand1
4  Carn/Sand2
```

My SQL query is this one, I just want the rows which start with "Lact":

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Type LIKE 'Lact%'
```

But it does not select any of them. I have tried diferent ways to do it but I always have the same problem with '/'.

Is there any way to solve this? I am using Access.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct wildcard in MS Access is `*`, not `%`.  So try:

```
SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Type LIKE 'Lact*'
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I thought the problem was the '/'

Answer (score 1):

use the keyword ALIKE if you want to use % as wildcard

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!